# Apache OFBiz 18.12.04 build failure

Tags: ofbiz

I am trying to build OFBiz 18.12.04 on Ubuntu Sever 20.04 and I get the following build failure:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '../apache-ofbiz/build.gradle' line: 133
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ofbiz'.
  Could not find method metadataSources() for arguments [build_2l69b6atnbul78s6vg112ejpi$_run_closure4$_closure66$_closure70$_closure71@1eeedb6d] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

I've opened up the build.gradle file and line 133 refers to metadataSources() getting an artifact from
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/milyn/flute/1.3/flute-1.3.jar. I can follow the link in my browser so my thinking is that it should be available so I don't understand why it is causing the build to fail.

```
java -version

------------------------------------------------------------
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

I am at a loss how to solve this. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Gradle 4.4.1, but follow https://ci.apache.org/projects/ofbiz/site/trunk/readme/html5/README.html#quick-start

Once Gradle jar installed inside gradmle/wrapper it will be OK

The rest seems OK

Comment: Those are the instructions that I followed  -- ./gradlew cleanAll loadAll is what results in the error

Comment: You should have better create another question than editing the one you initially created. 

Anyway, this seems quite weird and not related to OFBiz but your environment. 

For instance that's what we get with the last build in our own CI: https://ci2.apache.org/#/builders/48/builds/45/steps/3/logs/stdio

I checked the 133 line has not changed.

Comment: To be sure, I tried to remove all flute-1.3 related files and dirs from the Gradle cache. Then I ran "gradlew buidl" and the all flute-1.3 related files and dirs where downoaded in the Gradle cache w/o pb. So clearly you have a local issue.

Comment: Agreed that it was an local issue - did a clean install of the server and OFBiz ran first time. Thanks for the follow up nonetheless.